# Why is Visual Studio not seeing merged changes

Tags: tfs, merge

I created a branch in TFS off of the main branch. Then in this new branch I made a few changes and added a few files. I checked in my changes. Afterwards, I merged this branch back to the main branch.

Then I opened the main branch in Visual Studio and did a get latest version.  I expected to see the changes I made in the branch. But they are not there. If I look at the main branch in Source Control Explorer, I see the files that I added.

How do I get my merged changes to show up?

Comment: Do you have any pending changes in the main branch?  Are you sure all the merged files were checked in which include csproj and sln files?

Comment: You were right. The new files got checked into the branch. But for some reason, none of the modified files including the project file got checked in. I went back and reapplied the changes in the branch and checked them in. I merged again and everything showed up in the main branch.

Comment: Please post an answer for this case and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I did the check in, the files that were new got checked in. But the files that were changed didn't (and I somehow lost their changes). These new files made it back to the main branch. So I went back into my branch, and made the changes to the files again. Then I checked them in. Next I merged again. This time everything worked and my changes were in the main branch.